# OO-design issue

Tags: oop, smalltalk, pharo

I have a system where I have to model a `household`, which has a `TVSubscription`. This can either be a `digital` one, or an `analog` one.

A `user` logs into a `SetTopBox`. He can then rent `Movies`.

So the current scheme is the following:

```
//Existing instantiated variables in scope
aMovie
aUser
aSetTopBox
//End

--> execute this command: 
aUser rent: aVideo on: aSTB

Code:
User>>rent: aVideo on: aSTB
aVideo rentBy: self on: aSTB

Video>>rentBy: aUser on: aSTB
aUser rentActionMovie: self on: aSTB

User>> rentActionMovie: aMovie on: aSTB
aSTB rentActionMovie: aMovie by: self

STB>>rentActionMovie: aMovie by: aUser
(loggedInUser isNil)
    ifTrue: [ loggedInUser := aUser.
              --Do stuff to charge the movie]
    ifFalse: [ -- Show error that user is not logged in]
```

Technically speaking this is correct. But I have (Sorry for being anal) issues with this:

I have to pass `aSTB` 2 methods calls down to eventually use it. The double dispatch here is needed because I have `Child` and `Adult` and they can rent `AdultMovie` and `ChildrensMovie`. Therefore I use a double dispatch instead of typechecking (requirement). Therefore I thought of the following solution:

I can store `currentlyLoggedIn` on `aSTB`, and store a `loggedInOn` on `aSTB`. This however, makes the objects point to eachother.

My gut feeling tells me this is a bad smell. I'm not really sure how to fix it though.

Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
aUser rent: aMovie.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert, but just an alternative off the top of my head...

```
STB>>initialize
    aUser := UserNotLoggedIn new.

STB>>rentMovie: aMovie by: aUser
    (aMovie okayFor: aUser)
        ifTrue:  [ --Do stuff to charge the movie]

AdultMovie>>okayFor: aUser
    ^aUser canRentAdultMovie

ChildrensMovie>>okayFor: aUser
    ^aUser canRentChildMovie

User>>canRentChildMovie
    ^true

User>>canRentAdultMovie
    self displayErrorCannotRentAdultMovie
    ^false

Adult>>canRentAdultMovie
    ^true

UserNotLoggedIn>>canRentChildMovie
    self displayErrorUserNotLoggedOn
    ^false

UserNotLoggedIn>>canRentAdultMovie
    self displayErrorUserNotLoggedOn
    ^false

Child "just the same as User"

User>rent: aMovie.
    aSetTopBox rentMovie: aMovie by: self.
```

aUser rent: aMovie.

Answer (score 2):

Second alternative...

```
STB>>initialize
    aUser := UserNotLoggedIn new.

STB>>login
    aUser := self getUserFromAuthorisationCheck

STB>>rentMovie: aMovie by: aUser
    (aUser canRent: aMovie)
        ifTrue:  [ --Do stuff to charge the movie]

UserNotLoggedIn>>canRent: aMovie
    self displayErrorUserNotLoggedOn
    ^false

User>>canRent: aMovie
    aMovie ratingAge <= self ratingAge.

AdultMovie>>ratingAge
    ^18

Adult>>ratingAge
    ^18

ChildrensMovie>>ratingAge
    ^10

Child>>ratingAge
    ^10

User>>rent: aMovie
    aSetTopBox rentMovie: aMovie by: self
```

Answer (score 1):

**Thought**

You **look** so much at the relation between two objects,
then it could be that you want to model the relation as an **object**, too.

> An object is [anything that is visible or tangible and is relatively stable in form.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/object)

**Implementation Idea**

You create a temporary object which only lives as long as the relation between the two objects. The object can function as a mediator or method object, if you want.

My feeling is that it might be a case of over-engineering and not understood right away by the someone who reads the code.

Comment: Well, this is an assignment for a course I'm taking. I also have the over-engineering feeling.. I might try using the mediator to model the relationship.